# node JS console log ascii symbol

Tags: node.js, ascii, console.log

Hi
I am using node JS for my app, and I want to print ascii symbols in terminal.
[Here](http://www.asciitable.com/) is a table for ascii symbols. Please check Extended ASCII Codes field. I want to print square or circle, for example 178 or 219.

Can anyone say me, how can do it?
Thank you

Comment: I tried to print them like in html code . console.log("&178;");

Comment: And I cant find method to do this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Like several other languages, Javascript suffers from The UTF‐16
>   Curse. Except that Javascript has an even worse form of it, The UCS‐2
>   Curse. Things like charCodeAt and fromCharCode only ever deal with
>   16‐bit quantities, not with real, 21‐bit Unicode code points.
>   Therefore, if you want to print out something like , U+1D49C,
>   MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL A, you have to specify not one character
>   but two “char units”: "\uD835\uDC9C".

Please refer to this link: https://dheeb.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/gbu.pdf

Your desired character is not a printable ASCII character. On linux you can print all the printable ascii characters by running this command:

```
 for((i=32;i<=127;i++)) do printf \\$(printf '%03o\t' "$i"); done;printf "\n"
```

or

```
 man ascii
```

So what you can do is to print unicode characters. Here is a list of all the available unicode characters, and you can select one which is looking almost identical with your desired character.

http://unicode-table.com/en/#2764

I've tested on a windows terminal but it is still not showing the desired character, but it's working on linux. If it's still not working you had to make sure to set `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/rc.conf` and `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/locale.conf`.

So printing out something like this on node console:

```
console.log('\u2592 start typing...');
```

will output this result:

```
▒ start typing...
```

Comment: OP specifically asked about ASCII characters. 178 + 219 are both printable ASCII characters and they work without any problems at all in Windows. UTF-8 / UTF-16 is of course a whole different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you only care about ASCII that should not be a real problem at all. You *only* have to properly *escape* them. A good reference for this is https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

```
console.log('\xB2 \xDB')
```

Works for me with recentish node under Windows (cmd shell) and mac OS. For ASCII characters you can just convert them to hex and prepend them with `\x` in your strings. Give it a try with `node -e "console.log('\xB2')"`

Answer (score 0):

And when you try this answer, and it works, you might want to try:

node -e "console.log('\x07')"